# NSXMLParserDelegate Methods Not Being Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, nsxml

I've done an NSXML Parser before, but for some reason this time my NSXMLParserDelegate methods aren't being called when I call `parse`.

Here's where I call parse:

```
- (void)parseXMLFile:(NSString *)pathToFile 
{
    NSURL* xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
    _parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [_parser setDelegate:self];
    [_parser parse]; 
}
```

Here's my delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate Methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"section"])
    {
        _currentSection = [[Section alloc] init];   
        _currentSection.name = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"title"];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"section"])
    {
        [_sections addObject:_currentSection];
        [_currentSection release];
    }
}
```

And here's my header:

```
@interface Engine : NSObject <NSCoding, NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

My XML files are part of the project, so I can't figure out why the delegate methods wouldn't be getting called. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know they're not being called? Do you have logging code that you didn't post or are you using breakpoints?

Comment: I've used both breakpoints and logging. I took out all my logging code.

Comment: Are you sure that `_parser` isn't nil?

Comment: Yes. I have a check to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: and `xmlURL` is non-nil and there's a valid xml file at `pathToFile`?

Comment: Also check to see if `pathToFile` has any encoded characters that need to be percent escaped.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to check that your file contents are viewing the way you want by calling `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my pathname. I changed my `parseXMLFile` to:

```
- (void)parseXMLFile:(NSString *)pathToFile 
{
     NSString * filename = [pathToFile stringByDeletingPathExtension];
     NSString * extension = [pathToFile pathExtension];

     // Get  file contents
     NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension]];
    _parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [_parser setDelegate:self];
    [_parser parse];
}
```