# NSXMLParserDelegate methods are not called

Tags: iphone, xml, ios5, nsxmlparser, asiformdatarequest

Hi iam parsing an xml file and i got the response also which i have stored in a responseString.My problem with the delegate methods which are not being called, here's my parsing code

```
    -(void)getData
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://quizpro.testshell.net/api/quiz/4"];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  // Load XML data from web

 NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = 
 [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
 NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quiz.xml"];

 NSLog(@"store path is %@",storePath);

 [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

request.delegate=self;

[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];

if (!error)
{
     NSData *responseData=[request responseData];

     NSString *data  =[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

     NSString *usableXmlString = [data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

     NSLog(@"usableXmlString is %@",usableXmlString);

     NSData *usableData = [usableXmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:usableData];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];

}   
}  

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSLog(@"requestFinished method");

// Use when fetching text

NSString *responseString = [request responseString];  

** I get the entire data here ** 
NSLog(@"responseString is %@",responseString);


NSData *xData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//myCode.text = responseString;
//NSLog(@" response %@", responseString);

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xData];

[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
[parser release];
}
```

And i wrote the NSXMLParser delegate methods like below

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 {
 NSLog(@"parser/didStartElement");

 currentTag = elementName;


 if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"questions"])
 {
     exams_object=[[ExamsObject alloc]init];
     NSLog(@"%@",currentTag);
 } 

  if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"Question"])
 {
  exams_object=[[ExamsObject alloc]init];
 }

 if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"Response"])
 {
 exams_object.responseArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 }
   NSLog(@"%@",currentTag);

 }  

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 {
 NSLog(@"parser/didEndElement");

 if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"questions"])
 {
     exams_object=[[ExamsObject alloc]init];
 } 

 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Question"])
 {
 [mainArray addObject:exams_object];
 }

 }  

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)str
 {

 NSLog(@"parser/foundCharacters");

 if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"questionText"])
 {
 [exams_object.questionArray addObject:str];
 } 
 if ([currentTag isEqualToString:@"responseText"])
 {
 [exams_object.responseArray addObject:str];
 }  
 }
```

Thanks for help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `NSXMLParserDelegate` and `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` in your `.h` file ?

You are calling the method to parse the XML from delegate of `ASIHTTPRequest`
Check the flow of execution using `breakpoints`.

```
@interface yourClassName: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate, ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>
```

Also check these stackoverflow questions

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649119/nsxmlparserdelegate-methods-not-being-called)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374763/objective-c-nsxml-parser-delegate-methods-never-get-called)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added NSXMLParserDelegate in @interface and set parser.delegate=self in the class where you are using.

Comment: yeah i have added the delegate.